# Update a Table field with current time

Tags: vba, ms-access

Good day all,

I have a unbounded form with a subform (its data source is a table named SaleDetail).
On the Main Form there is a text box for the Sales ID also unbounded.

I have created a button with the following code:

```
Private Sub btnEndSale_Click()

Dim strPostTime As String

strPostTime = "UPDATE SaleDetail " & _
        "SET [TIMEOUT] = Time()" & _
        "WHERE SaleDetail.SID = Forms!Sales.Form.sSID"

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.Requery

End Sub
```

I am trying to get the current time to update the records in the SalesDetail table once the SID on the Main Form matches the SID in the SalesDetail Table but it is not working, but if I substitute `Forms!Sales.Form.sSID` with an existing ID (eg 9) it works. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SetWarnings False` suppresses information, so can be an obstacle to trouble-shooting.  And it can be totally avoided with a parameter query.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim strUpdate As String

strUpdate = "UPDATE SaleDetail SET [TIMEOUT] = Time() " & _
    "WHERE SaleDetail.SID = which_SID;"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strUpdate)
With qdf
    .Parameters("which_SID").Value = Forms!Sales.Form.sSID.Value
    .Execute dbFailOnError
End With
MsgBox db.RecordsAffected & " records updated"
```

Comment: I am little confused. Won't this line `.Parameters("which_SID").Value = Forms!Sales.Form.sSID.Value` read `.Parameters(Forms!Sales.Form.sSID.Value).Value = Forms!Sales.Form.sSID.Value` ?

Comment: When the db engine sees `which_SID` in the `UPDATE` statement text, it interprets `which_SID` to be a parameter (because that is neither the name of a function nor the name of a field in the table).  So, in human-speak, the line you asked about means "use the value from `Forms!Sales.Form.sSID` for the value of the parameter named `which_SID`"

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
strPostTime = "UPDATE SaleDetail " & _
        "SET [TIMEOUT] = Time()" & _
        "WHERE SaleDetail.SID = " & Forms!Sales.Form.sSID
```

Comment: Thank You, that did it.

Comment: @newbieDBBuilder note that this solution has a SQL injection vulnerability that the other solution does not have. SQL injection vulnerabilities are a security issue, but also a bug waiting to happen. Consider learning proper parameterization instead of concatenating form fields into queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think that newbieDBBuilder is not asking about SQL Server query which could use parameters. His code is:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
```

which is MS Access command and queries Access db.

Comment: Parameter-queries are not related to SQL-Server (you may have mixed it up with, with stored-procedures). Its a general design pattern to prevent SQL injection. See [Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com/). Can be used with DAO or ADODB

Comment: This is correct but he is querying Access table using  DoCmd.RunSQL

Comment: So why not advise to use`Dao.Execute`? The use of`DoCmd`is ugly most times, as there are better options.